# How to stop multiple links when clicking the same link

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hyperlink, tabs

I have a data grid with a hyperlink control that users can click and it will open a new tab displaying information about the selected item.  My issue is that if the same item is clicked 3 times I get 3 new tabs on my browser.

Is there a way open the tab the first time the link is clicked and as long as it is open and someone selects the link can it put the focus on the already created tab instead of opening a new one?

The hyperlink control has target set to "_blank".

I'm using C# and Asp.net 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a name in the `target` attribute:

```
<asp:HyperLink
    NavigateUrl="https://www.google.com"
    Text="Go to Google"
    Target="SameWindow"
    runat="server"/>

<asp:HyperLink
    NavigateUrl="http://stackoverflow.com"
    Text="Go to StackOverflow"
    Target="SameWindow"
    runat="server"/>
```

HTML example:

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="SameWindow">Go to Google</a>
<br />
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="SameWindow">Go to StackOverflow</a>
```

This is (I believe) identical to using the javascript `window.open` function to pass in a name for a window. After the named window is opened once, subsequent calls to `window.open` with that name passed in will load the new URL in the window that's already open.

Here's an example snippet. You might have to run the code snippet in the full JSFiddle page due to security restrictions (CORS).

```js
var openTarget = function() {
  console.log(this);
  var target = this.getAttribute("attr-target");
  window.open(target, "ExampleName");
}

var elems = document.querySelectorAll("button");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elems, function(e) {
  e.addEventListener("click", openTarget);
});
```

```html
<button attr-target="https://www.google.com/">Open Google</button>
<button attr-target="http://stackoverflow.com/">Open StackOverflow</button>
```

Comment: Thank you that prevented subsequent windows from opening in new tabs.  The issue now is that it highlights the existing tab but doesn't move focus too it.   In IE the already opened tab begins to blink blue but focus stays on the home page where my data grid is.  Is there a way to move focus to the new tab?

Comment: @JerryWarra That's browser-specific behavior. You _might_ have some luck with `window.focus` in _some_ browsers.

Comment: Is there a way to do window.focus on the hyperlink?

Comment: @JerryWarra I'm not aware one, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I noticed it works fine in Chrome, but IE and Firefox it doesn't.

Comment: @JerryWarra I'm glad I could help! Be sure to choose an accepted answer to your question by clicking on the check mark (✅) at the top left of the answer.

Comment: Sorry about my delay in doing that.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

just set the target to some name like

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="anyname">a link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of this simle code

```
<p onclick="window.open('www.sample.com','mywindow').focus()" >Visit Now</p>
```